# How to import `State` from `catalyst` version 22.2.1?

Tags: python, catalyst

I tried to run an [old code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hidehisaarai1213/introduction-to-sound-event-detection/notebook) on my local machine, but running:

```
from catalyst.dl import State
```

results into

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'State' from 'catalyst.dl'
```

[I also tried](https://catalyst-team.github.io/catalyst/v20.04.2/_modules/catalyst/core/state.html)

```
from catalyst.core.state import State
```

and

```
from catalyst.core import State
```

But it looks like `State` is gone. The [documentation](https://catalyst-team.github.io/catalyst/v22.02.1/search.html?q=state&check_keywords=yes&area=default) seems to not return any results.

I am using Catalyst Version 22.2.1

Comment: Your second link is to documentation for a class `catalyst.core.state.State`, which means you're missing one level of submodule in your import statement.

Comment: ah right there is also No module named '`catalyst.core.state`'

Comment: Oh, I see, the first documentation link is to the older version. I'm sorry, I don't have any other insights, I'm not at all familiar with the library, but hopefully somebody who does know more about it will come by eventually.